# Powershell change default variable scope in script

Tags: powershell, scope

Is there an option to change the default variable scope to private for a script? E.g. via PSDefaultParameterValues?

I don't like that variables are used from parent when they are note defined in the current scope.

```
Set-PSDebug -strict
$a = 5
function foo() {
    Write-Host $a
    $a = 8
    Write-Host $a
}
foo
$a
```

This will output 5, 8, 5

Currently I have to prefix every variable with 'private:'.
This will output "The variable '$private:a' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.", 8, 5

Everything as expected but it looks ugly.

```
Set-PSDebug -strict
$private:a = 5
function foo() {
    Write-Host $private:a
    $private:a = 8
    Write-Host $private:a
}
foo
$private:a
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can globaly modify this behaviour, from `get-help about_scope`

> Unless you explicitly make the items private, the items in the parent scope
>       are available to the child scope. However, items that you create and change
>       in the child scope do not affect the parent scope, unless you explicitly 
>       specify the scope when you create the items.